# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse - Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I am new to AJAX and It seems like I might be missing a quite fundamental detail. If I do this locally without using Wordpress, it works correctly. I am sending you the link:

But if I create a function with Wordpress it comes out:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at
> JSON.parse

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'conta_visite');
function conta_visite(){
    
    $dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/users";
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    wp_mkdir_p( $dir );
        
}
if(isset($_POST['getCustomerCount']))
{

    $dbfile = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/visitors.db"; // path to data file
    $expire = 3; // average time in seconds to consider someone online before removing from the list
    if(!file_exists($dbfile)) {
        echo json_encode(['success'=> false,'error_message'=>"Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " NOT FOUND!"]);
        die();
        //die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " NOT FOUND!");
    }

    if(!is_writable($dbfile)) {
        echo json_encode(['success'=> false,'error_message'=>"Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " is NOT writable! Please CHMOD it to 666!"]);
        die();
        //die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " is NOT writable! Please CHMOD it to 666!");
    }

    $count = CountVisitors($dbfile, $expire);
    if(is_numeric($count)){
        $out = $count; // format the result to display 3 digits with leading 0's
        echo json_encode(['success'=>'true', 'customer_count'=>$out]);
    }
    else 
    {
        echo json_encode(['success'=> false, 'error_message'=>"count is not numeric"]);
    }
}
else{
    echo $dbfile;
    echo json_encode($_POST);
}


function CountVisitors() {
    global $dbfile, $expire;
    $cur_ip = getIP();
    $cur_time = time();
    $dbary_new = array();

  $dbary = json_decode(file_get_contents($dbfile),true);
    if(is_array($dbary)) {
      
      foreach($dbary as $user_ip => $user_time){
        if(($user_ip != $cur_ip) && (($user_time + $expire) > $cur_time)) {
                $dbary_new[$user_ip] = $user_time;
            }
      }
    }
  
    $dbary_new[$cur_ip] = $cur_time; // add record for current user

    $fp = fopen($dbfile, "w");
    fputs($fp, json_encode($dbary_new));
    fclose($fp);

    return count($dbary_new);
}

function getIP() {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = "0.0.0.0";
    }
    return $ip;
}

    
?>

<p id="customer_count">Customers Online: <span></span></p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function updateCustomerCount() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: {getCustomerCount: true},

        success: function(response) {

            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            //var data = response;
            console.log(response);
            if (data.success) {
                $("#customer_count span").text(data.customer_count);
            } else {
                console.log(data.error_message);
            }

        },
        error: function(response, request, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
setTimeout(updateCustomerCount, 2000);
} 
updateCustomerCount();
        
</script>

<?php
}
```

This is the Demo link in Wordpress:
You can find the counter in the upper right corner of the header.

---

Can you help me? Because I'm going crazy and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong....

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON` (generally) means that your "JSON" is actually "HTML".  Look at the actual value before you try to parse it.  If it's a plugin/framework that's parsing it, look in the browser network tab to see what the server is returning.  You'll likely find it's an HTML error page.

Comment: In your code, move `console.log(response);` to *before* JSON.parse(response) to see what the *actual* response is.

Comment: _"This is my code:"_ - located where? It looks like you are simply sending your request to the current page URL, and try to process it within your functions.php or something? If you are doing AJAX in WP, you should do it the _proper_ way: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/

Comment: @CBroe The code is placed in the function.php.

Comment: @freedomn-m I did and it returns the whole page  `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it-IT">
<head>...`

Comment: Does that look like JSON to you?

Comment: Your `$.ajax({` doesn't have a `url` parameter, so will use the current page's url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this should do what you're looking for. I've rewritten your code for better WordPress integration.

First, you'll need to create a new javascript file name `visitor-counter.js` and place it a `js` folder in your themes directory. This will be used for our jQuery and ajax request.

**`/js/visitor-counter.js`**

```js
(function($) {

    window.VisitorCounter = window?.VisitorCounter || {

        /**
         * @type {object} Temp storage object
         */
        _temp: {},

        /**
         * Get a PHP variable.
         *
         * @param varName
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getVar(varName) {
            const vars = window?.VisitorCounterVars;
            return vars?.[varName];
        },

        /**
         * Make ajax request to server, store response in temp object.
         *
         * @returns {Promise<unknown>}
         */
        request() {
            return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
                const url = this.getVar('ajaxUrl');
                const action = this.getVar('ajaxAction');
                const post_id = this.getVar('post_id');

                if (url && action) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            action: action,
                            post_id: post_id
                        },
                        cache: false
                    }).then(response => {
                        this._temp.count = response.data;
                        accept(response);
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                } else {
                    reject('Visitor counter ajax url or action not available.');
                }
            });
        },

        /**
         * Get the count value.
         *
         * @returns {number}
         */
        getCount() {
            return parseInt(this._temp?.count || 0);
        },

        /**
         * Refresh data continuously.
         *
         * @param {callback} callback
         * @param {number} timeout
         */
        refresh(callback, timeout) {
            this._temp.lastRefreshed = Date.now();

            this.request().then(() => {
                const now = Date.now();

                callback.apply(this);

                const timeoutDiff = now - this._temp.lastRefreshed;

                // If request took longer than timeout, run next refresh instantly.
                if (timeout && timeoutDiff >= timeout) {
                    this.refresh(callback, timeout);
                }

                // Request was quicker than timeout, queue next refresh call.
                else {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.refresh(callback, timeout);
                    }, timeout - timeoutDiff);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // Initiate refresh loop
    VisitorCounter.refresh(function() {
        $('#customer_count span').text(VisitorCounter.getCount());
    }, 2000);

})(jQuery);
```

Next add the below to your themes functions.php file...

**`/functions.php`**

```php
class VisitorCounter {
        
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * @var string $file Relative path to the tracking file.
     */

    public $file = 'users/';

    /**
     * @var int $expires Automatically expire vistor after X amount of seconds.
     */
    
    public $expires = 3;

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public static function init() {
        if ( !static::$instance ) {
            static::$instance = new static( ...func_get_args() );
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the full database file path and create file if not exists.
     *
     * @return string|false
     */
    public function getPath() {

        $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
        $path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . ltrim( $this->file, '/' ) . 'product-view-id-' . $post_id . '.db';
        $exists = file_exists( $path );

        if ( !$exists ) {
            wp_mkdir_p( dirname( $path ) );
            $exists = touch( $path );
        }
        return $exists ? $path : true;
    }
    /**
     * Read the contents of the visitors database file as a JSON.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData() {
        if ( $path = $this->getPath() ) {
            if ( $contents = file_get_contents( $path ) ) {
                if ( $json = @json_decode( $contents, true ) ) {
                    return $this->cleanData( $json );
                }
            }
        }

        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Clean the visitor data by removing expired entries.
     *
     * @param array $input
     * @return array
     */
    private function cleanData( array $input ) {
        $now = time();

        foreach ( $input as $ip => $timestamp ) {
            if ( $timestamp + $this->expires < $now ) {
                unset( $input[ $ip ] );
            }
        }

        return $input;
    }

    /**
     * Add visitor count data.
     *
     * @param string $ip
     * @param int $timestamp
     * @return array
     */
    public function logUser() {
        
        // Get current data.
        $data = $this->getData();

        // Add new entry.
        if ( $ip = $this->getUserIp() ) {
            $data[ $ip ] = time();
        }

        // Clean data before saving.
        $data = $this->cleanData( $data );

        // Encode and save data.
        file_put_contents( $this->getPath(), wp_json_encode( $data ) );

        // Return data.
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current users IP address.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getUserIp() {

        // In order of preference, with the best ones for this purpose first.
        $address_headers = [
            'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
            'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
            'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
            'HTTP_FORWARDED',
            'REMOTE_ADDR'
        ];

        $client_ip = null;

        foreach ( $address_headers as $header ) {
            if ( !empty( $_SERVER[ $header ] ) ) {
                /*
                 * HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can contain a chain of comma-separated
                 * addresses. The first one is the original client. It can't be
                 * trusted for authenticity, but we don't need to for this purpose.
                 */
                $address_chain = explode( ',', $_SERVER[ $header ] );
                $client_ip = trim( $address_chain[ 0 ] );
                break;
            }
        }

        return $client_ip;
    }
}

/**
 * Helper function for visitor counter class.
 *
 * @return VisitorCounter
 */
function visitor_counter() {
    return VisitorCounter::init();
}


/**
 * Register an ajax request handler.
 */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_active_visitor', 'handle_visitor_activity' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_active_visitor', 'handle_visitor_activity' );
function handle_visitor_activity() {
    $controller = visitor_counter();
    $controller->logUser();
    wp_send_json_success( count( $controller->getData() ) );
}


/**
 * Load our javascript file on the frontend data.
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
if ( is_product()) {
    // Load the counter javascript file after `jquery` in the footer.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'visitor-counter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/visitor-counter.js', [ 'jquery' ], '1.0.0', true );

    // Load php data that can be accessed in javascript.
    wp_localize_script( 'visitor-counter', 'VisitorCounterVars', [
        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'ajaxAction' => 'active_visitor',
        'post_id'=> get_the_id()
    ] );
}
} );
```

Things to lookup...

WordPress ajax handlers (`add_action( 'wp_ajax_' )` and `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' )`) documentation can be found here:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv__requestaction/

WordPress JSON responses `wp_send_json_error()` and `wp_send_json_success()`:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/

Loading javascript on the frontend:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/

Comment: You saved me! I am studying the code you have been my salvation.... I don't want to take advantage but I could use some help. I am trying to rename the file by taking the id of the current page via `get_the_id()`. I also tried with `global $post` but it doesn't work, it fails to call the function.... How can I do this? Thanks...

Comment: `public function getPath() {

        $path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . ltrim( $this->file, '/' ) . get_the_ID() . '.db';
`
Not Work...

Comment: @Naycom using `get_the_ID()` in an ajax call wont work as the request has no context, you'll need to pass the ID in the request. I'll update my answer later when I have some time.

Comment: Hi, I've solved it, I'll update the code. I managed to get the id of the current post in the `wp_localize_script` function and pass it later in ajax and get back via `$GET` the id in the `public function getPath()`. I also added `if(is_product())` because the function only had to start in the product. If of course there are improvements to be made I am always grateful for your corrections!